# Get Element Node Value of XML using XElement in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have the following XML file saved:

```
<E:Events xmlns:E="Event-Details">
   <Date>12/27/2012</Date>
   <Time>‎11:12 PM</Time>
   <Message>Happy Birthday</Message>
</E:Events>
```

I am using `XElement` to load the above XML file.
I want to get the Element Value of `Date, Time and Message` i.e. 12/27/2012, ‎11:12 PM and `Happy Birthday`.
How can I retrieve these values.
I have searched a lot on this but could not find anything.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you just tried getting the element from your XElement node?

> XElement.Element(" < element name >");

will return the nodes you need.

Try the code below:

```
string text = "<E:Events xmlns:E=\"Event-Details\"><Date>12/27/2012</Date><Time>‎11:12 PM</Time><Message>Happy Birthday</Message></E:Events>";
XElement myEle = XElement.Parse(text);
Console.WriteLine(myEle.Element("Date").Value);
Console.WriteLine(myEle.Element("Time").Value);
Console.WriteLine(myEle.Element("Message").Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to retrieve the values, but now I am facing one more issue.
I have a MainPage.xaml UI, and I try to assign these retrieved values on the UI, like for e.g. 
txtMessage = myEle.Element("Message").Value;
But this throws a null reference exception. 

Any idea why??..

Comment: It would be better to post that a separate question, please post your xaml and the relavant code behind where you are trying to assign the values. Also, if my answer helped you please mark it as an answer.